# Отправка формы на почту AJAX + JQuery + PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Нужно отправлять с лендинга на почту форму обратной связи, но что-то пошло не так и форма не обрабатывается php, в консоли получаю "POST http://localhost:3000/save.php 404 (Not Found)"

Помогите, что я делаю не так?

UPD: Когда перехожу по адресу http://localhost:3000/save.php файл save.php просто скачивается... То есть он есть но почему через него не обрабатывается?!

Код следующий:

```js
$(document)
  .on('submit', '#main-form', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form_data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/save.php",
      data: form_data,
      success: function() {
        alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено!");
      }
    });

  });
```

```html
<form class="b-form" id="main-form">
  <div class="b-form__row">
    <label for="name" class="b-label">Ваше имя</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="b-input b-form__input" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
  </div>
  <div class="b-form__row">
    <label for="email" class="b-label">Электронная почта</label>

    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="b-input b-form__input" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <div class="b-form__help">Обязательно для заполнения</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-form__row">
    <label for="phone" class="b-label">Телефон <span class="b-aster">*</span></label>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="b-input b-form__input b-phone__mask" placeholder="Телефон" required/>
    <div class="b-form__help">Обязательно для заполнения</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-form__row">
    <input type="submit" class="b-button b-button_blue" value="Отправить" />
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```html
<?php

$recepient = "uma199041@mail.ru";
$sitename = "Бюро Сервис";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone \nEmail: $email";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как работает php-сервер?   что за сервер на 3000 порту?

Comment: Вы уверены что на этом хосте есть окружение php? На 3000 порту обычно работает сервер nodejs по умолчанию. И в проекте как раз есть node_modules. Если это так, то вам стоит запустить встроенный в php сервер для обработки .php файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки [php](http://php.net/) [нужен сервер](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.php) и интерпретатор. Просто так php не работает.
Нужна связка [Apache/PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.apache2.php) или Nginx/PHP, для теста можно и [встроенный сервер](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Answer (score 0):

В стрелочной функции не тот `this`:

```
$(document)
  .on('submit', '#main-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let form_data = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: исправил но так же 404